# Build list with customised widget count per row dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following list which is contructed in the format I need where it is 3 widgets per row.

But this is hard coded.

How could I have looped this or some cleaner solution so that I could repeat this as many times as I want?

Like right now I have 4 rows. Say I want 10 rows, 3 widgets each, I don't want to be copy pasting this 10 times

plus I do not know how many rows I'm going to get. It depends on some external data. Can I get some guidance? Thanks.

```
ListView(
    children: [
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 8),
            child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 0)), // these numbers are indexes which differs for each widget
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 1)),
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 2)),
                ],
            ),
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 8),
            child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 3)),
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 4)),
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 5)),
                ],
            ),
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 8),
            child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 6)),
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 7)),
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 8)),
                ],
            ),
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 8),
            child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 9)),
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 10)),
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test', 11)),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ListView.builder`.

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: _customWidget('test')),
                  Expanded(child: _customWidget('test')),
                  Expanded(child: _customWidget('test')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
      ),
```

And if you have dynamic `List<model>`, you can set length of list to `itemCount` in `ListView`.

**Update**

full code with 'Fake Simple List Item'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Training extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TrainingState createState() => _TrainingState();
}

class _TrainingState extends State<Training> {
  Map<int, List<String>> mMap;

  void _initMap() {
    mMap = Map();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      List<String> subtitleList = List();
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        subtitleList.add("Sub $j of Title $i");
      }
      mMap[i] = subtitleList;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initMap();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: mMap.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: _getChildren(mMap[index]),
              ),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _getChildren(List<String> list) {
    List<Widget> output = List();
    list.forEach((element) {
      output.add(_customWidget(element));
    });
    return output;
  }

  Widget _customWidget(String s) {
    return Expanded(child: Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(8), child: Text(s)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I do this, will be issues with index I think. I need to pass down index for each widget. This would end up repeating 3 identical widgets per row.

Comment: I updated my post for your request. of course codes depend on the type of data you have

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GridView with List.generate. Set `myLength` to the amount for widgets it should generate. Use `[index]` inside each widget to get specific data from a array.
ex: If you have a array `myProducts` set the length to my `myProducts.length` then inside use `myProducts[index]`

```
GridView.count(
   mainAxisSpacing: 6,
   crossAxisCount: 1,
   childAspectRatio: (200 / 67), // (width/height)
   children: List.generate(
      myLength, (index) {
         return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 8),
            child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test)),
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test)),
                    Expanded(child: CustomWidget('test)),
                ],
            ),
        );
      }
   ),
),
```

Comment: Is there a way I could modify this to get correct index values? Cos first index value is 0 and I plan to send that value down to the CustomWidget. For first loop, I should get index 0, 1, 2 instead of 0, 0, 0. Next loop 3,4,5 and so on. One possibilioty is to write some logic method which takes in indexes and perform calculates and outputs new index value for usage. Trying to avoid it.

Comment: [index+1] or apply logic to the index through a function